# C++ Queue error

Tags: c++, queue, deque

This is my Queue declaration here

```
// TODO: Declare a queue here - e.g. as a global variable
queue<string>myQueue;
```

This here is where I think my problem is. Whenever I run the program, I get an error stating "deque iterator not dereferencable."

```
string receiveMessage()
{
    string messageValue = noMessage; // Don't change this value unless there is a message - default is improtant

    messageQueueMutex.lock();
    try
    {
        // TODO: Set hasMessages to true if your queue is not empty, otherwise set it to false:
        if(!myQueue.empty())
        {
            bool hasMessages = true;
        }
        else
        {
            bool hasMessages = false;
        }

            // TODO: Remove the first message from your queue and place it in messageValue:
            messageValue = myQueue.front();
            myQueue.pop();

    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "Exception occurred - check your code!" << endl;
    }
    messageQueueMutex.unlock();

    return messageValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `unlock()` here, `std::mutex` will automatically unlock when it goes out of scope. Also, `hasMessages` will not be accessible after the if-else statement b/c it is declared inside the scopes of the if-else statement. So, you need to do:

```
bool hasMessages;

if(!myQueue.empty())
{
    hasMessages = true;
}
else
{
    hasMessages = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the queue is empty, this code will still attempt to remove the first element from the queue. If you don't believe me, just [ask your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

This is, of course, undefined behavior.